# Puppet add line in a file only if the line is absent in file_line puppet resource

Tags: file, module, puppet

I try to add line in resolv.conf file using puppet file_line resource but it add lines again and again for every puppet run in my agent. How can I skip adding line in a file if it is present in a file using file_line puppet resource. I can't use other modules and exec resource for it.My code is,

```
file_line { 'resolve config':
      ensure  => present,
      match   => "^nameserver *",
      path    => '/etc/resolv.conf',
      line    => 'nameserver 192.168.1.1',
}
```

Comment: That actually looks fine. The regular expression is a bit odd. I would have written `match => '^nameserver ',` as the `*` isn't adding anything and single quotes are preferred, but apart from that all fine.

Comment: Are there more than one `nameserver` lines in `resolv.conf`? The docs, https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/4.25.1/readme#multiple, say that multiple matches cause an error by default, thought that doesn't sound like what you are seeing

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your file, because that code should work as advertised.

Comment: Yep. I tested and this code works fine.

Comment: ok let take the task like I need to add 3 lines in a file only if the lines are absent in the file through puppet using file_line resource??